# How to add currency converter to my flutter e-commerce app?

Tags: flutter, dart, currency-exchange-rates

I'm creating an app where users can upload products in their country's currency and the product will be visible for other users in their own country's currency.

For example, a user from France should be able to set the price of the product in Euros and other users viewing the product, say one of them is viewing the product from Australia then the price should be converted to Australian dollars.

How do I achieve this with flutter?

If I have the user's country details already, is there any converter plugin or API that does this?

The plugin or API should obviously update with rates. I'm using Firebase for the database to store the uploaded product and details. Or maybe I can save the product price in multiple currencies with their current rates at the time of upload and the price wont change with the change in rates after upload.

Comment: Since exchange rates are not fixed, what do you expect that plugin to do? Which source of information do you want for this? How frequently should it update and where do you want to save that information?

Comment: The plugin or api should obviously update with rates.I'm using Firebase for database to store the uploaded product and details.Or may be i can save the product price in mutiple currencies with thier current rates at the time of upload and the price wont change  with the change in rates after upload

Answer (score 1):

use the api to get the updated conversion rates. You can use this [api](https://exchangeratesapi.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`forex`](https://pub.dev/packages/forex) package to access exchange rates easily.

From their examples section:

```
quotes = await Forex.fx(
  quoteProvider: QuoteProvider.ecb,
  base: 'JPY',
  quotes: <String>['EUR', 'USD']);

print('Number of quotes retrieved: ${quotes.keys.length}.');
print('Exchange rate JPYEUR: ${quotes['JPYEUR']}.');
print('Exchange rate JPYUSD: ${quotes['JPYUSD']}.');
```

Please note that *getting* the exchange rates of currency is the easy part in the mess that banking is... be sure to think about all the edge cases in your application if you want to do more than just display a price tag.